# How can I query data from database in django 2.2

Tags: python, django

I´m building a app that manage a book library and i need to retrieve data from sqlite3 database

I'm using Django 2.2. and I read some books and they some like this:

```
class LanguageView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Language.objects.get()
    serializer_class = LanguageSerializer
```

```
    class Language(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        paradigm = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And my serializer class is

```
class LanguageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Language
        fields = ('id','name','paradigm')
```

And I expect the output of `{"id":1,"name":"Learning Python", "paradigm":"object-oriented"}`

but it raises an error: `Class 'Language' has no 'objects' member`

Comment: The queryset should be `Language.objects.all()`. Did you by any change define a manager on your `Language` model?

Comment: Even if i put Language.objects.all() it don't work. And not, i didn't define an manager on my language model

Comment: That appears to be a warning from your IDE, not an actual runtime error. You should ignore it.